# How do I allow an additional AWS user to gain access to EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to do:

```
[ec2-user@xxxxxxxxx x]$ aws eks update-kubeconfig --name prod-eks-v2 --role-arn arn:aws:iam::9xxxxxxxxxxeks-v2-cluster-ServiceRole-xxxxxxxxxx

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeCluster operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:user/ecr is not authorized to perform: eks:DescribeCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:cluster/prod-eks-v2
```

This is for an *additional* user I've added. I've already added them to the `aws-auth` configmap by adding the following:

```
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/xxxxxxxxx
    username: admin
    groups:
        - system:masters
```

Trying to assume the role manually:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/eksctl-prod-eks-v2-cluster-ServiceRole-xxxx --role-session-name test-eks-role

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/ecr is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/eksctl-prod-eks-v2-cluster-ServiceRole-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This is the trust relationship json for the cluster-ServiceRole...:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I resolve this? I followed the docs from https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amazon-eks-cluster-access/

---

**Update**:

I modified the trust relationship to now be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/xxxxxx"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

And can successfully do:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/eksctl-prod-eks-v2-cluster-ServiceRole-OCH0HY9R9WGS --role-session-name test-eks-role
```

But I still get the `...is not authorized to perform: eks:DescribeCluster on resourc...` when doing `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name prod-eks-v2`.

---

**Update 2:**

I added the user to the `AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy` role which now allows me to generate the config successfully with `aws eks update-kubeconfig`... However I get a `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)` when attempting anything via `kubectl`....

The bottom of the kubeconfig file looks like:

```
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:cluster/prod-eks-v2
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - prod-eks-v2
      - -r
      - arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/eksctl-prod-eks-v2-cluster-ServiceRole-xxxxxxxxxx
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
```

**Update 3:**

Super confused... I can manually generate token and verify it with:

```
aws-iam-authenticator token -i prod-eks-v2 -r...
aws-iam-authenticator verify -t ...
```

But as mentioned doing anything with `kubectl` shows `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`...

doing `kubectl get pods -v=10`: shows:

```
...
I1115 12:36:42.163298   10509 request.go:942] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
...
```